# SQL : How to improve performance for INNER JOIN with CASE

Tags: sql-server, performance, inner-join, hana

I have a big performance issue regarding to a query which need to read a filter table for the filters and read the source data table related to that filters.
So my filters table looks like this;

```
FILTER_ID CUSTOMER COUNTRY DEPARTMENT
   1                  UK      DEP1
   2       CUS1       US      DEP1
   3       CUS1
```

and here is my source data table;

```
ROW_NO CUSTOMER COUNTRY DEPARTMENT
  1      CUS1     UK      DEP1
  2      CUS2     UK      DEP1
  3      CUS3     UK      DEP1
  4      CUS1     US      DEP1
  5      CUS1     SG      DEP3
  6      CUS1     UK      DEP3
```

For each filters on the filter table i need to get rows from source data table. But if the column on FILTER table is EMPTY, we need to read all members for that column existing in the source data table. Lets say for FILTER_ID 1, we need to read all customer for COUNTRY = UK and DEPARTMENT = DEP1 from the source table.

This is how result table should look like;

```
FILTER_ID   ROW_NO   CUSTOMER   COUNTRY   DEPARTMENT
   1           1       CUS1       UK        DEP1
   1           2       CUS2       UK        DEP1
   1           3       CUS3       UK        DEP1
   2           4       CUS1       US        DEP1
   3           1       CUS1       UK        DEP1
   3           4       CUS1       US        DEP1
   3           5       CUS1       SG        DEP3
   3           6       CUS1       UK        DEP3
```

I am using conditional join and it is working fine but problem is, it is very SLOW!

```
select t1.FILTER_ID, t2.* from FILTER_TABLE as t1
inner join SOURCE_DATA as t2 on 
CASE WHEN t1.CUSTOMER    = '' THEN t2.CUSTOMER   ELSE t1.CUSTOMER END = t2.CUSTOMER and
CASE WHEN t1.DEPARTMENT  = '' THEN t2.DEPARTMENT ELSE t1.DEPARTMENT END = t2.DEPARTMENT and
CASE WHEN t1.COUNTRY     = '' THEN t2.COUNTRY    ELSE t1.COUNTRY END = t2.COUNTRY
```

Is there a way to optimize this code ?

Comment: Is you FILTER_TABLE fixed? In sense, does it always have only 3 rows?

Comment: No it is not fixed, it has 12K rows. and source table has 85K rows depending on condition.

Comment: You can rewrite your `CASE` statements into combinations of `OR` (because `t2.CUSTOMER = t2.CUSTOMER` will be almost every time ok (unless `t2.CUSTOMER` is `NULL`)), for example:
    `((t1.CUSTOMER    = '') OR (t1.CUSTORMER <> '' AND t1.CUSTOMER = t2.CUSTOMER))`. Please, check it and tell us the result.

Comment: Can you divide your FILTER_TABLE into 9 tables that will contain only "not empty" colums? Then write 9 SELECT with union all between them, every select joins only on fixed columns without any CASE?

Comment: @Rokuto with that way it is running 2x faster. 30min+ is finished 14min now. Thank you!

Comment: @sepupic i have 12 columns to be checked but at least if i move all filled columns to a new table and just use normal inner join it is very fast. Currently in my production data example, i checked 5 columns has no empty fields. After changing CASE statement for that 5 columns to t1.COLUMN = t2.COLUMN, it finished in 30 sec (previously 30min)
even i split into 2 table also should work fine i think. thank you

Comment: @bilen appying functions to fields *prevents* the optimizer from using indexes. That's why changing from CASE to OR resulted in an improvement. What is the execution plan though? ARe the fields covered by indexes? Is the server using seeks or table scans?

Comment: @sepupic it seems that you nailed it, I think you should put your comment as answer since this is an interesting question and would be nice have the solution that worked as a proper answer (other answers are being posted that may or may not work).

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez it's actually a *very* common mistake to try and create one big "smart" query with "dynamic" parameters. The results are always disappointing, as those "smart" queries result in inefficient execution plans and/or  can't use indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree, that is why I think that the solution of converting that complex joins to simple regular joins is worth of being an answer (also, the question itself is well written so it can useful to other people)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you Ἀριστοτέλης for your "smart" answer but unfortunately before writing a long queries with unions, sub queries or workarounds; i wanted to try if it is possible with a single query logic. Rokuto and sepupic gave good answers already i am still trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, i think, it will be quickly:

```
select t1.FILTER_ID, t2.* from FILTER_TABLE as t1
inner join SOURCE_DATA as t2 on 
 t1.CUSTOMER    = t2.CUSTOMER and
 t1.DEPARTMENT  = t2.DEPARTMENT and
 t1.COUNTRY     = t2.COUNTRY 
where t1.CUSTOMER <> '' and t1.DEPARTMENT <>'' and t1.COUNTRY <> ''
union all
select t1.FILTER_ID, t2.* from FILTER_TABLE as t1
inner join SOURCE_DATA as t2 on 
CASE WHEN t2.CUSTOMER    = t2.CUSTOMER 
where t1.CUSTOMER = '' and t1.DEPARTMENT <>'' and t1.COUNTRY <> ''
union all
select t1.FILTER_ID, t2.* from FILTER_TABLE as t1
inner join SOURCE_DATA as t2 on 
CASE WHEN t2.DEPARTMENT    = t2.DEPARTMENT 
where t1.CUSTOMER <> '' and t1.DEPARTMENT = '' and t1.COUNTRY <> ''
union all
select t1.FILTER_ID, t2.* from FILTER_TABLE as t1
inner join SOURCE_DATA as t2 on 
CASE WHEN t2.COUNTRY    = t2.COUNTRY 
where t1.CUSTOMER <> '' and t1.DEPARTMENT <> '' and t1.COUNTRY = ''
```

Comment: thank you for answer but your solution also similar to above. At the same time different columns can be empty. Lets say CUSTOMER = ' ' and DEPARTMENT = ' ' 
I have 12 columns in prod server and combinations will be crazy if i try to use all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
select t1.FILTER_ID, t2.* from FILTER_TABLE as t1
inner join SOURCE_DATA as t2 on 
 IIF(t1.CUSTOMER = '',t2.CUSTOMER, t1.CUSTOMER)  = t2.CUSTOMER and
 IIF(t1.DEPARTMENT = '', t2.DEPARTMENT,t1.DEPARTMENT) = t2.DEPARTMENT  and
 IIF(t1.COUNTRY = '',t1.COUNTRY,t2.COUNTRY) = t2.COUNTRY
```